# Can a self signed Java Applet have full permissions if executed on the localhost?

Tags: java, security, applet

I know a real Java Applet on a Website should be officially signed to work properly and have full access. I just want to test the functionality of a java applet on my localhost without buying a certificate. So the question to me is can a self signed Java Applet have full permissions if executed on the localhost?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it might involve changing the security settings of the Java plug-in and the browser.